# Tratar de alterar una tabla en MS SQL usando una variable

Tags: sql-server, datatables, sql, mssql

Hola estimados amigos de stackoverflow, actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación y para modificar datos de una base de datos sql actualmente existente; y en este momento me encuentro tratando de modificar una tabla alterando el valor por defecto de una columna; el problema es que lo quiero hacer utilizando una variable que lee el nombre del constraint en la base de datos para poder modificar el valor por defecto de la columna pero al correr el query el resultado es el siguiente.

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 72 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de
>   '@MONEDA'. Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 74 Sintaxis incorrecta
>   cerca de '@MONEDA'.

Tengan en cuenta que el query que corro me arroja el resultado del nombre de la constraint correctamente al ejecutar un print @moneda pero cuando lo paso por el alter table parece no tomar el valor.

Este es mi query.

```
DECLARE @MONEDA VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @MONEDA = (select    constraint_name
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details]
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    select schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name
    from sys.foreign_keys fk
        inner join sys.tables fk_tab
            on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        inner join sys.tables pk_tab
            on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols
            on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        con.[definition]
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition]
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) 
            a
where (table_view = 'dbo.saclie' and (constraint_name like '%EsMoneda%')));
ALTER TABLE SACLIE
DROP CONSTRAINT @MONEDA;
ALTER TABLE SACLIE ADD CONSTRAINT
@MONEDA DEFAULT ((1)) FOR EsMoneda;
```

Algo muy similar a esto

```
ALTER TABLE SACLIE
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF__SACLIE__EsMoneda__0F2D40CE;
ALTER TABLE SACLIE ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF__SACLIE__EsMoneda__0F2D40CE DEFAULT ((1)) FOR EsMoneda;
```

Pero el query no me funciona y no logro modificarlo si no indico manualmente el nombre de la constraint.

¿Alguno quisas me pueda orientar por favor?

Agradecido de ante mano.

Comment: Es que no puedes usar una variable para estas clausulas SQL, en todo caso deberías escribir una sentencia dinámica y ejecutarla

Comment: Algo así `SET @SQL = 'DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @MONEDA ';'` y luego usar `sp_executesql`

Comment: Si exactamente lo logre pero sin la nescecidad de ejecutar un store procedure

Answer (score 0):

resolvi mi problema leyendo la pregunta de:

[ALTER TABLE my_table ADD @column INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614101/alter-table-my-table-add-column-int)

Resulta que solo tenía que ejecutar la instrucción exec para que sql server leyera la cadena de caracteres como si ejecutase el atert table directamente aprovechando la variable @moneda que había declarado y asignado con set previamente usando un select.

Por lo que después de todo sustituí:

```
ALTER TABLE SACLIE
DROP CONSTRAINT @MONEDA;
ALTER TABLE SACLIE ADD CONSTRAINT
@MONEDA DEFAULT ((1)) FOR EsMoneda;
```

Por

```
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE SACLIE DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @MONEDA + ';');
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE SACLIE ADD CONSTRAINT '+ @MONEDA + '@MONEDA DEFAULT ((1)) FOR EsMoneda;');
```

Quedando el código final de este modo.

```
--DECLARARE LA VARIABLE PARA MODIFICR EL VALOR POR DEFECTO DE ESMONEDA EN SACLIE Y CAMBIARLO TODO POR DEFECTO A 1
DECLARE @MONEDA VARCHAR(MAX);
--USARE LA VARIABLE PARA ES MONEDA
SET @MONEDA = (select    constraint_name
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details]
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    select schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name
    from sys.foreign_keys fk
        inner join sys.tables fk_tab
            on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        inner join sys.tables pk_tab
            on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols
            on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        con.[definition]
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition]
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) 
            a
where (table_view = 'dbo.saclie' and (constraint_name like '%EsMoneda%')));
--AQUI USARE LA FUNCION EXECUTE DE SQL SERVER PARA QUE RECONOSCA LA CADENA DE CARACTERES COMO SI FUESE UN ALTER TABLE Y PUEDA APROVECHAR LA VARIABLE @MONEDA
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE SACLIE DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @MONEDA + ';');
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE SACLIE ADD CONSTRAINT '+ @MONEDA + '@MONEDA DEFAULT ((1)) FOR EsMoneda;');
```

La respuesta final del motor de base de datos entonces fue 'Comandos completados correctamente.'

No mas errores gracias por la ayuda!.